# Deploying ASP.NET website admin tool onto Web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2005, C#.

Visual studio 2005 has an in built ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool which allows me to manage users.

However, I am required to deploy the functionality (add user, edit user role, etc) and GUI of the tool on a webpage.

May I know if there are any blog or sites which provides guide on this?

**Functionality I am looking for:**

1. List all users and their roles
2. Edit user roles
3. Edit user active/inactive
4. User account lockdown
5. Add new user

Comment: try this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/03/09/547402.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the Memebership with Login controls available to achieve the same thing that is done by ASP.NET Website Administartion Tool.

http://ripalsoni.wordpress.com/2007/03/16/how-to-use-login-control-in-net/

Comment: this site is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a guide which shows how to implement the tool on a webpage. thanks anyw.

Comment: membership with login controls? what do you mean?